# Using the RPI 4 as a remote access tool

Tags: remote

I would like to be able to connect the RPI 4 to any device that exposes HDMI output and a
usb interface for connecting a keyboard/mouse. I understand that this might require additional hardware.
I would then like to able to connect remotely to my RPI and view the HDMI output of the connected device and relay keyboard and mouse commands from my computer over the RPI to the connected device.

The reason is to mimic local access of the connected device, regardless of the underlying operating system it uses.

I don't know the name of this concept.

Please point me to some literature, blogs or docs that can help me get started.

Comment: Something like the [PiKVM](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/pikvm-v3-hat-for-raspberry-pi-4)?

Comment: That's definietly what I had in mind but its very feature rich. I would just want hdmi video capture and usb input. I dont care about anything else. 
Looks like they rolled their own OS for this too?

Comment: Just in case, since it has not been mentioned explicitly yet, you do need additional hardware for the HDMI capture (eg., an HDMI to USB A/V capture adapter, which are cheap and plentiful I think).  Presuming this uses standard USB camera protocols (they probably do, and at a glance at least some of them are clear about that), there should be no problem accessing the input as a video stream.  That said, before you buy anything: 1) Avoid things that refer to special drivers or software, 2) Check around on the linux compatibility.

Comment: @goldilocks you have the best answer so far. If you want credit, post it as an answer and I will accept it.